# How do I switch tabs in my terminal like I do in Chrome

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I have the shortcuts open, but I cannot force it to be:

"Ctrl + Tab" to go to the tab on the right

It's like it doesn't recognize the tab key.

How do I enforce that to switch a tab, I press Ctrl + Tab?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, for one or another reason, this interface does not allow <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to be set as a shortcut to move to the next tab. However, you can change the assignment using the tool `dconf-editor`.

Install `dconf-editor`, launch it and navigate to /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/keybindings/ and click the "next-tab" setting. Uncheck the "Use default value" checkmark and fill in `<Control>Tab`. Proceed in a similar way for "prev-tab".

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed prev to `<Control><Shift>Tab` to mimik chrome